# How to use one HttpClient instance to request many URLs with different domain?

Tags: micronaut

The docs shows that Http client shoud set a URL or a service id to instantiating:

```
@Client("https://api.twitter.com/1.1") 
@Inject 
RxHttpClient httpClient;
```

How to use one HttpClient instance to request many URLs with different domain?

```
@Client 
@Inject 
RxHttpClient httpClient;

httpClient.retrieve( HttpRequest.GET("https://twitter.com/") )
httpClient.retrieve( HttpRequest.GET("https://www.google.com/") )
```

The code will return error:
`No value specified for @Client\r\nPath Taken`

Comment: I have the same problem. I have urls from my database so I do know them at compile time

Answer (score 0):

The [`HttpClient`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/HttpClient.html) and subsequent [`RxHttpClient`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/RxHttpClient.html) in [Micronaut](http://micronaut.io/) are scoped to a given URL.  They maintain some configuration, load balancing, scheduling, SSL contextual information and HTTP client filters scoped to the configured `URL`.  In your example you would need to inject two different clients.

```java
@Inject 
@Client("https://api.twitter.com/1.1") 
RxHttpClient twitterClient;

@Inject 
@Client("https://www.google.com") 
RxHttpClient googleClient;

twitterClient.retrieve( HttpRequest.GET("/statuses/user_timeline") )
googleClient.retrieve( HttpRequest.GET("/some/available/endpoint") )
```

Also note the Injected `RxHttpClient` can be setup to [use a configuration path if desired](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientBasics).

Comment: I mean URLs can be from any domain, not only 2 domains. Spring RestTemplate and WebClient can request any domain URLs.